# How do I use % with input variable in LIKE query, SQLite?

Tags: python, input, sql-like

I’m using the following code to assign a variable as input for identifying the records with particular ending, but it’s not working... please help!

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("music.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

publisher_ends_with = input("Enter the ending: ")

ending_search = cursor.execute('''SELECT Publisher, COUNT(Publisher) FROM BL_music_records WHERE Publisher LIKE ?''', ('%’ publisher_ends_with,)).fetchall()
```

Comment: Edit the question to explain "not working", what happens, what should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value for the LIKE statement was not formatted correctly:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("music.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

publisher_ends_with = input("Enter the ending: ")

ending_search = cursor.execute('''
SELECT Publisher FROM BL_music_records WHERE Publisher LIKE ?
''', (f'%{publisher_ends_with}',))

ending_search_results = ending_search.fetchall()

for row in ending_search_results:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Got it!